# How could I go back to the original equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose, I have a system of equations:

$a + b = 7$

$a^2 + b^2 = 25$

Now I will leave it in linear form, adding the equations

$a^2 + a + b^2 + b = 32$

Here is the problem, can I go back from this linear equation to the previous two? I have been trying without reaching anything concrete.

Comment: You might need to solve for $a$ and $b$ and then find the original equations . There is no other way i think

Comment: The system formed by the first two equations, and the system formed by only the last equation are not equivalent. In fact, the last equation has a solution for every value of $b$, while the original system has only one solution. Therefore, the original system is not a consequence of the last equation.

Comment: "from this linear equation": it is a quadratic equation.

Comment: What do you mean by "linear form" and "linear equation"?

Comment: An equivalent system would have been, replace the last equation by the sum of the first and last equation. This leaves you with the system $$\begin{align}a+b&=7\\a^2+a+b^2+b&=32\end{align}$$ This and the original one are equivalent. The original system can be recovered from this.

Comment: @arugula It doesn't have a solution for every value of $b$. Consider $b=6$, which gives $a^2+a+10=0$.

Comment: @Arthur Just don't waste my time with such superbly stupid comment. There are clearly, not one, but two solutions for $a$ in that equation.\

Comment: @argula That _really depends_. Most people, even people asking questions on this site, would consider that to have no solutions. Complex numbers aren't _that_ well known, sadly. Also, there is context: [tag:algebra-precalculus] usually only concerns real numbers. Now tell me how my comment was "superbly stupid" for thinking in real numbers, or "just don't waste my time" with such trivialities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two equations together give a line and a circle in the $ab$-plane, and the solution to the system are the two intersection points between the circle and the line (assuming there are any).

The last equation is just the equation for a circle in the $ab$-plane. It's a different one from the previous circle, but it will go through the two points that solves the original equation set. However, it will have (infinitely) many more solutions, and as such, you can't use that equation / circle alone to get back to the two exact points that the original equation set gave.

Answer (score 2):

Adding two equations and keeping only the sum is an irreversible process.

For instance adding $a=0$ and $b=0$ yields $a+b=0$, which admits the "alien" solution $a=1,b=-1$, not contained in the original setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't go back.  The original pair of equations has two solutions, $a=3,b=4$ and $a=4,b=3$.  The first equation represents a straight line and the second represents a circle.  The solutions are the two points they intersect.  The final equation represents a whole circle, a different one, with equation $(a-\frac 12)^2+(b-\frac 12)^2=\frac {63}2$.  You can combine this with either of the first two and have the same two points of solution.

Answer (score 0):

The key problem that occurs is that while your original pair of equations yields just $a=3,b=4$ and $a=4,b=3$ as solutions, the combined equation has many other different solutions, even for $a=3$.

---

You can rearrange your equation to $$a+b=\frac{2(4+b)(4-b)}{(a+1)-b}$$
Let $a=3$, then $3+b=2(4+b)$ (the second parts cancel as $a+1=4)$$\to b=-5$. Note this rules out every other possibility except when $b=4$, check that in the original function and you'll see it works. Given therefore that when $a=3, b=4$, or $b=-5$, for these cases $a+b=7$ or $a+b=-2$

---

Take $a=2b+3$ to eliminate the $4+b$. You then get $3b+3=8-2b \to b=1$. No other solutions will be found except potentially when $b=-4$. This means $a=-5$, and bringing that through the combined equation gives $32$, so also a solution. At $b=1, a=5$, hence $a+b=6$, for $b=-4, a=-5$, giving $a+b=-9$.

---

Setting $(a+1)-b=2$ yields $b=-5,b=3$, with $a=-4, a=4$ respectively. We've already seen this so no need to re-cover,

Hence from the equation
$$a^2+b^2+a+b=32$$
We can say:
$$a+b=7$$
$$a+b=6$$
$$a+b=-2$$
$$a+b=-9$$

and potentially others I couldn't find.